# Save SkiaSharp Canvas with Bitmap Image with finger painting

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, skiasharp

I am trying to paint on bitmap image and then updated drawing needs to be saved

till now I was able to get the image on canvas and also I am able to draw on bitmap image but the problem is when I export the stream I could not see my drawing I only get the bitmap stream

Here is the code which I implemented till now

Global Variable

```
 private SKBitmap sKBitmap;
```

Contructor

```
                using (Stream stream = ImageDataStream)
                {
                    sKBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
                }
```

InvalidatedSurface

```
 private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        globalSurface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = globalSurface.Canvas;
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        canvas.Clear();
        if (sKBitmap != null)
        {
            canvas.DrawBitmap(sKBitmap, info.Rect, BitmapStretch.Uniform);
        }

        foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
        {
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
        }

        foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
        {
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }
```

Canvas Saving Code

```
using (SKImage image = SKImage.FromBitmap(sKBitmap))
            {
                SKData data = image.Encode();
                var imageBytes = data.ToArray();
            }
```

while saving I get the original image rather than updated one with drawing not sure what wrong I am doing  with this

Comment: you are saving the Image, not the canvas.  The SKSurface object has a Snapshot method you can call to capture the entire canvas.

Comment: @Jason I tried that the app get crash with that method and I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/saving

Comment: "get crash" is not a helpful description.  What is the specific line of code that causes the crash?  What is the exception?

Comment: @Jason thanks for that Snapshot hint I figured out my mistake and this snapshot thing worked for me, Thankyou so much